# Access contacts list from Pebble JS

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch

I'm trying to build a Pebble watchapp that can share via SMS directly from the watch. Is it possible to get a list of contacts in the Pebble SDK or JS without having a separate app running on the device? I can't find anything on the topic in the docs, so I'm thinking I might have to try some sort of PhoneGap integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible in PebbleKit JS. The JS code is run in a sandboxed environment, so at the moment you can't access anything from the device (beyond doing HTTP requests and location lookups).